# Read File ACL with PowerShell from C# Command Application

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm new to StackOverflow as a user and new to C#, so forgive my ignorance.  I'm trying to retrieve event log permissions using the PowerShell Get-Acl cmdlet.  For now I'm trying to get the results displayed to the command line with the following code:

```
public void PsScripts()
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
        runspace.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;

        using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke())
        {
            invoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process");
        }

        runspace.Open();

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(@"Get-Acl c:\Windows\system32\winevt\logs\Application.evtx | Format-List");
        pipeline.Commands[0].MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.Error, PipelineResultTypes.Output);

        PSObject[] result = pipeline.Invoke().ToArray();

        //Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
        var error = pipeline.Error.ReadToEnd();
        runspace.Close();

        if (error.Count >= 1)
        {
            string errors = "";
            foreach (var Error in error)
            {
                errors = errors + " " + Error.ToString();
            }
        }
        //var results = powerShell.Invoke();
        foreach (object s in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
```

The results I receive are:

> "Cannot find path 'c:\Windows\system32\winevt\logs\Application.evtx'
>   because it does not exist."

What I was expecting to see is:

> "Path   :
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Windows\system32\winevt\logs\
>            Application.evtx Owner  : NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE Group  : NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE Access : NT SERVICE\EventLog Allow 
>   FullControl
>            NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
>            BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl"

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!  The best way to keep knowledge is to give it away! :)

Comment: Try to execute your application as Administrator and ensure the path is valid. Also, why don't you use the Directory.GetAccessControl method?

Comment: OS bitness? Application bitness?

Comment: Thank you jisaak! I took your recommendation and used the Directory.GetAccessControl method.... much easier!